# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

---

### gradle-wrapper

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {

        google()

        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong

        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }

}

allprojects {

    repositories {

        google()

        jcenter()

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {

    delete rootProject.buildDir

}
```

---

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0.

Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.0/gradle-4.0.0.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.0/gradle-4.0.0.pom

Comment: Should be working fine, try using a VPN, maybe it can't establish a connection to Google servers.

Comment: I am using a VPN

Answer (score 14):

I struggled in a similar question after upgrading the Android Gradle Plugin Version from `3.3.0` to `4.0.0` of a React Native project as suggested by Android Studio. I followed the answer but it still do not sync correctly.

Finally I run `rm -rf node_modules` and re-install all the dependencies by `npm install`. After that I sync again and it sync correctly. I guess that there are some caches in different node modules that are not cleaned properly. I hope if someone encounter similar problem can try and see if my answer fix the problem.

Comment: Worked for me, tnx

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after Invalidating caches under File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart
Later deleted node_modules under project folder and then did an npm install.
On Click of File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files resolved this issue